# Webpack bundle throwing error with specific react version

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, webpack

I am working on a react project and we were recently given the requirement that it must support Google Chrome version 34.  In order to get it to display I had to lower the react version from 16.0.0 to 15.6.2.  There is an error I am trying to resolve but I am not sure where it is coming from.  It is originating from the webpack bundle.

```
decoderReactBundle.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

The line is:

```
var parentHotUpdateCallback = window["webpackHotUpdate"];
```

If I move the react version back to 16.0.0 the error goes away and all is well except that it won't display in Chrome 34.

This is my package.json file.  I figure that I have to adjust the version of one of the dependancies but I am not sure which one.

```
{
  "name": "ava",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "broadwayjs": "0.0.2",
    "query-string": "^5.0.1",
    "react": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.2",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.14",
    "react16-spinjs": "^3.0.1",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
    "dev": "webpack -d --watch",
    "build": "react-scripts build webpack",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue - did you find a solution?

Comment: I found that using the following combination of dependancies made it work.  "react": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.2","webpack": "3.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.0"

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you can try using the [Webpack ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/) to set a reference for `window` in the build:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  'window': window
})
```

Anytime Webpack sees a reference to `window` it should be replaced with the instance of window at the time of build.